# Bluetooth music playback slow and choppy

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa

How do you diagnose slow choppy sound playback with Bluetooth headsets on Ubuntu 14.04?

My headset worked perfectly on 12.04, but after I upgraded to 14.04, I can still pair just fine and select the headset's A2DP profile in Sound Settings just fine, but attempting to play any audio only results in slow choppy output. Also, most applications continue to output through my laptop's speakers. Only the Gnome "sound effects" are output through the headset.